# Is there something im not understaning about the fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I do not understand how this method works. Here is the code

```
BOOL isDir = NULL;
BOOL returnVal;
path = @"/Users/me/Desktop/kkk";
returnVal = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir];
```

And here are the results if:

1) kkk is a file

```
returnVal = NO
isDir     = NO
```

2) kkk is an empty directory

```
returnVal = YES
isDir     = YES
```

Scenario #2 seems to work as expected, but according to the documentation:

```
path
The path of a file or directory. If path begins with a tilde (~), it must first be expanded with stringByExpandingTildeInPath, or this method will return NO. 

isDirectory
Upon return, contains YES if path is a directory or if the final path element is a symbolic link that points to a directory, otherwise contains NO. If path doesn’t exist, this value is undefined upon return. Pass NULL if you do not need this information.
```

So for scenario #1 shouldnt the result be the following?

```
returnVal = YES
isDir     = NO
```

**1) Edit**
For the comments below.

But the files do exist. I create the file manually to test it. lol. its only a program with 4 lines of code. I have both file/folder on the desktop. First i put a file there called "kkk" (with no extention) then i remove the file and place a folder there called "kkk".  It works for the folder, but not for the file.  Interestingly, if the file *has* an extension, it works. So is there something wrong with a file with no extension ? (are you guys still not able to reproduce it with no extention?)

**2) EDIT**

Thanks for helping me solve this guys. I have my Mac set to display the extension of files. But it seems Mac as an odd behavior. I select the file "kk.plist" and then rename the file to "kk" as you see in the image. As soon as i do this Mac OSx automatically selects the hide extension option. So when i thought the file was "kk", it was still "kk.plist" with its extension hidden.  As you can see, both files have the same extension, one is hidden, the other is not. I didnt realize hidden extensions can be applied to one file only. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue using similar pathnames. I get the expected outcome each time.

Comment: I can't reproduce either. You probably have a typo in your path.

Comment: I'm guessing that in the first case "kkk" doesn't exist where you're looking for it.

Comment: How do you create a file? Make sure your editor does not add a default extension. Print out contents of your directory in Terminal to make sure the name is right.

Comment: Launch Terminal.  In the Terminal window, run `ls -l /Users/me/Desktop/kkk*`.  Copy the output and paste it into your question.

Comment: `BOOL isDir = NULL;` - what's this supposed to do? (Yes, **do turn on** `-Wall` while compiling!)

Comment: Create the file with `touch kkk` on the terminal, don't save a file from TextEdit etc.

Comment: You say that you are creating the file “with no extention” (sic), but you haven't said how you are creating the file. Get Info on it in the Finder and make sure it has the name you think it has. Then, copy it, and paste it into your source file—your editor will paste the file's path, which you can compare against the one you're trying to query.

Comment: thanks all. i updated the question. Im not sure how to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) kkk is a file
>
> ```
> returnVal = NO
> isDir     = NO
> ```
>
> ⋮
>
> So for scenario #1 shouldnt the result be the following?
>
> ```
> returnVal = YES
> isDir     = NO
> ```

Yes. But be wary of the Finder hiding things from you when you're trying to verify results from this method.

As you found, one example is hiding extensions: you gave a path with no extension and were surprised when it didn't find a file that you thought had no extension; in truth, it still had an extension, which the Finder had hidden, so it still did not match the path, so the result you got was correct.

The other example is hidden (a.k.a. invisible) items. You may get a result of YES for a file that you can't find in the Finder. The Go command will temporarily reveal an invisible directory, but won't help you for files.

Whenever `fileExists:isDirectory:`'s results surprise you, and the Finder appears to show that the results are wrong, try to `ls` the path in the Terminal:

```
ls -dl /path/to/item
```

If that command prints a description of the item, then it exists. If it prints an error, then it doesn't. You can also tell from the output whether the item is a directory or not.